# Algorithm - converting nested data to plain data

Tags: algorithm, matrix, tree

I have the following nested data structure:

```
Node 1  
  |--- Node 11  
       |--- Node 111
  |--- Node 12  
       |--- Node 121  
       |--- Node 122  
       |--- Node 123  
  |--- Node 13  
       |--- Node 131  
Node 2  
  |--- Node 21  
       |--- Node 211
       |--- Node 212
etc.
```

and I'm trying to write an algorithm that converts it into a "plain" 2D matrix, like this:

```
| 1  | 11  | 111 |  
| 1  | 12  | 121 |  
| 1  | 12  | 122 |  
| 1  | 12  | 123 |  
| 1  | 13  | 131 |  
| 2  | 21  | 211 |  
| 2  | 21  | 212 |  
etc.
```

however, I'm having a bit of trouble doing it efficiently, since I can't just traverse the tree and fill the matrix: as you can see the matrix has more cells than the tree has nodes, due to redundant data in all columns except the last.

Note that, like in the example, all leaves of the tree will have the same number of parents, i.e.: the same "nesting depth", so I don't need to account for shorter branches.

I'm sure there's already an algorithm that does this properly, but I don't know how this particular problem is called, so I couldn't find it. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure there is any specific name for this, maybe "tree flattening", but I suppose there are several ways in which you could flatten a tree anyway. You can do it with something like this (pseudocode since there is no language tag):

```
proc flatten_tree(tree : Node<Int>) : List<List<Int>>
    matrix := []
    flatten_tree_rec(tree, [], matrix)
    return matrix
endproc

proc flatten_tree_rec(tree : Node<Int>, current : List<Int>, matrix : List<List<Int>>)
    current.append(tree.value)
    if tree.is_leaf()
        matrix.append(current.copy())
    else
        for child in tree.children()
            flatten_tree(child, current, matrix)
        loop
    endif
    current.remove_last()
endproc
```

If you need to produce an actual matrix that needs to be preallocated you would need two passes, one to count the number of leafs and depth and another to actually fill the matrix:

```
proc flatten_tree(tree : Node<Int>) : List<List<Int>>
    leafs, depth := count_leafs_and_depth(tree, 0)
    matrix := Matrix<Int>(leafs, depth)
    flatten_tree_rec(tree, [], matrix, 0)
    return matrix
endproc

proc count_leafs_and_depth(tree : Node<Int>, base_depth : Int) : Int
    if tree.is_leaf()
        return 1, base_depth + 1
    else
        leafs := 0
        depth := 0
        for child in tree.children()
            c_leafs, c_depth := count_leafs_and_depth(child, base_depth + 1)
            leafs += c_leafs
            depth = max(c_depth, depth)
        loop
        return leafs, depth
    endif
endproc

proc flatten_tree_rec(tree : Node<Int>, current : List<Int>, matrix : Matrix<Int>, index : Int)
    current.append(tree.value)
    if tree.is_leaf()
        matrix[index] = current
        index += 1
    else
        for child in tree.children()
            index = flatten_tree(child, current, matrix, index)
        loop
    endif
    current.remove_last()
    return index
endproc
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Just a note: in the second implementation (the matrix one), the `current.remove_last()` statement is never executed, since you `return` in both branches of the IF statement above. I think you meant to put the statement just before the return statement(s)

Comment: I would just call it a depth-first traversal of the tree.